# How to know what code has been optimized out?

Tags: gcc, optimization, clang, compiler-optimization, static-analysis

Is there a way to get information during or after compilation about what parts of the code have been optimized out, but without looking at the assembly or executing the code.

It'd be nice to know immediately if a big code chunk gets optimized away.

Comment: Why would this be nice to know? That's the optimizer's *job*, to optimize out big chunks of code. It removes complex abstractions, helper methods, all kinds of things humans write to make code easier to read and reason about. Why do you feel like you need to second-guess the optimizer? Are you having a real problem?

Comment: @Cody Gray it could expose bugs in the code I'm compiling (or even in the compiler), and it would satisfy my curiosity :)

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but your expectations do not match what compilers actually do. Whether you're trying to find dead code or to find bugs that cause code that should run to be skipped, it is not information that a compiler can provide in an easy-to-read form.

With a compiler that translates each line of source code into a sequence of machine instructions, the compiler could easily tell you that it didn't include anything corresponding to a particular line. Of course it couldn't tell you if a line was translated to machine instructions but those machine instructions in fact won't ever be executed — code reachability is [undecidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem) — but I don't think that's what you're after anyway.

The problem is that modern optimizing compilers are a lot more complex than that. A piece of code is often copied around and compiled multiple times under different assumptions (specialization, partial evaluation, loop unrolling, …). Or, conversely, pieces of code can be merged together (function inlining, …). There isn't a simple correspondence between source code and machine code. (That's why debuggers sometimes have trouble reporting the exact source code location of a binary instruction.)

If a big chunk of code gets optimized away, that may simply because it's one of many specialized copies and that particular specialization never happens (e.g. there's separate code for `x==0` and `x!=0`, and separate code for `y==0` and `y!=0`, and `x` and `y` are never 0 together so the `x==0 && y==0` branch is eventually dropped). It may be something generated by a compile-time conditional instruction, such as a C macro that the compiler optimizes; this happens so often in C code that if compilers reported all such instances, that would create a lot of false positives.

Getting useful reports of potentially unused code or suspicious-looking program code that could indicate a bug requires a rather different kind of static analysis than what compilers do. There are tools that can do that, but they're typically not the same tools that convert source code to optimized machine code. Making static analysis tools that both detect potential problems often enough to be useful and don't produce so many false positives that they're practically unusable is not easy.

Answer (score 1):

```
gcc -S
```

will output the assembly code that would have been passed to the assembler (and eventually been linked into the executable).  If you squint the right way (and are patient), you can work backwards from that to confirm whether a given bit of code has actually been included in the executable, or was optimized away.

Obviously not something you'd do unless you have a suspicion that something was going on, given the time and effort required...

Comment: I know about -S, but I hope there is a more straightforward solution.